# Tomcat status Failed in Redhat 8

Tags: tomcat, redhat

We're currently working on installing Tomcat v9.0.67 on Redhat 8. However, following some guides, when we try to start the service it finishes with exit code.

I'm pasting the error and also the tomcat.service config. Do you know what could be wrong?

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat 9 servlet container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.345.b01-1.el8_6.x86_64/jre/"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"

Environment="CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat/latest"
Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/latest"
Environment="CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/latest/temp/tomcat.pid"

ExecStart=/bin/bash /opt/tomcat/latest/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/bin/bash /opt/tomcat/latest/bin/shutdown.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a copy of my tomcat.service file which works:
NOTE: close to your file.  Maybe try adding `syslog.target` to After= in the `[Unit]` section.  `ExecStart` and `ExecStop` might be incorrect also, try
`catalina.sh start` and `catalina.sh stop`.

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat Server
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true'
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/usr/local/tomcat/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/usr/local/tomcat/tomcat/tomcat.pid
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M'
ExecStart=/usr/local/tomcat/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start
ExecStop=/usr/local/tomcat/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```